# How to set Preferred Orientation when Navigating back to home page

Tags: flutter, dart

How to fix screen orientation cannot back to normal when press the back button?

here soruce code: https://github.com/iyansr/traffic-manager-master

I've set Orientation inside and outside void initState() on both page, but when i go back to homepage, the screen orientation still lanscape.

I want the homepage always in potrait mode
and the second page is always landscape

on home.dart:

```dart
...
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Set portrait orientation
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    ]);

    _dateTime = DateTime.parse(initDate);
  }
...
```

on counterpage.dart (landscape):

```dart
class _CounterPageState extends State<CounterPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
    ]);
  }
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply also perform your `SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations` calls in the [**`State.dispose`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/dispose.html) methods of whatever pages you return from. This means that the orientation will be set when the `Navigator` pops your page.
In your case, you would want to set the preferred orientation back to landscape when leaving the `CounterPage`, meaning that you would have to add the following code:

```dart
class _CounterPageState extends State<CounterPage> {
  @override
  void dispose() {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    ]);
    super.dispose();
  }

  // ...
}
```

If you have any other page that you navigate to from your home page, these pages also need to set the preferred orientation back to potrait in their `dispose` methods.

Answer (score 2):

initState() isn't called when you back, because your old page is still created, but not active. Maybe the simplest result here will be called setPrefferedOrintations() in dispose() method on second screen

```
class _CounterPageState extends State<CounterPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
    ]);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Set portrait orientation
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    ]);
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, dispose method didn't work well in my case, what I did was while navigating to the landscape page I used 'then' callback and reset my preferred orientation (i.e. portrait mode) there, this callback method would call when you navigate back from landscape page thus resetting your preferred orientation in homepage;

```
  onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context)
                    .pushNamed('/horizontalModePage')
                    .then((_) => SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
                          DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
                          DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
                        ]));
```